# Is "long since" a conversational phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage, register

Is "long since" a conversational phrase? Or is it more likely used in written document?

> Even though her parents have **long since** died, she still talks about them in the present tense.
>
> Have you ever read Scarlet Letter? Yes, I've **long since** read it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say ***long since*** is definitely a *declining* usage, so you should only use it if you actually *want* to use an expression that at least *some* people will think is slightly "quaint / dated". Consider [this usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20long%20since%20disappeared%2Cdisappeared%20long%20ago&year_start=1888&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20long%20since%20disappeared%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisappeared%20long%20ago%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chas%20long%20since%20disappeared%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisappeared%20long%20ago%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...showing that ***long since*** has dramatically lost currency over the past century, whereas my alternative phrasing using ***long ago*** has remained constant.

---

Personally, I've always had a bit of a problem with the *semantics* of ***long since***, because to my mind ***since*** implies ***after*** [some contextually-relevant time]. So in contexts like OP's, I always think *"Since **when**?"* Maybe many other people have had the same problem, and that's why the usage is dying (has died?) out.

Comment: You've put two very specific phrases into your search there. When I ran "long since" on its own there is a decline, but then a slight upturn in the most recent years available. 'the upturn is a little more noticeable on the phrase "long since died". There's clearly a decline in its use as a conversational phrase but is still very much in use as an idiom. I certainly use it.

Comment: @Astralbee: But I specifically went to the trouble of ***adding*** the word ***had*** to my first search term to "scale" the results so they'd both fit on the same chart! The ***relative*** prevalence of either expression compared to the other is irrelevant to my point - all that matters here is the ***change over time*** values. I don't deny there are plenty of native speakers for whom ***long since*** is still perfectly natural. But it's been "quaint" to me for well over half a century - and I've even explained ***why*** I feel like that, in my final paragraph.

Comment: Note that if you just chart the 2-word sequence ***long since***, there's no telling how many "spurious" hits get scooped up. Including, but not limited to, things like *It's been **so long since** we've had a big fat Greek wedding!*, which I don't have a problem with.

Comment: (And *long since read it* simply [***flatlines***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=long+since+read+it%2Cread+it+long+ago&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cread%20it%20long%20ago%3B%2Cc0) against *read it long ago* in NGrams, as expected.)

Comment: With "long ago", I think I should use the past simple, right?

Comment: @StephenLiu: The ***main*** reason for using Present Perfect *(I **have** read it)* is to imply *continuing up until, or highly relevant to, **time of utterance***. But *usually*, if you specifically qualify some past action as having taken place ***long ago***, that would tend to *emphasize* the difference between "then" and "now". So as a rule of thumb, it's probably fair to say Present Perfect and ***long ago*** don't mix very well together.